# Problem with solving task using central limit theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Here is the task that i have problem with

> In a company, there are n people working independently. The probability that a randomly selected person is on sick leave is 0.1. How large should this team be so that the probability that at least 5 people are sick is at least 0.95?

I assume it can be done using Bernoullie scheme but it is required from me to do it with central limit theorem, and i dont know how to solve it

Comment: You have the sum of n bernoulli distributed random variables, which is binomial distributed as $X\sim \textrm{Bin}(n,0.1)$. Now applly the central limit thorem. $P(X\geq 5)=1-P(X\leq 4)\approx 1-\Phi \left(\frac{4-n\cdot 0.1}{\sqrt{n\cdot 0.1\cdot 0.9}} \right)\geq 0.95$ Solve the inequality for $n$. Be aware, that $n$ will be a approximation.

Comment: you can't solve it using the central limit theorem because it's an asymptotic statement, not a non-asymptotic. the question doesn't make sense

Comment: @callculus42 shouldn't we use continuity correction?

Comment: @SineoftheTime Yes, you can do it. If n is large it will not have a big impact.